# Pyodbc error when running the same code from different VENV

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to run a specific SQL command executing a stored procedure from a new venv I created and I keep getting this error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 3 (""): Data type 0x63 has an invalid data length or metadata length. (8016) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I am executing the exact same statement, with the exact same values:

```
sql = "exec insertpart ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? output"
values = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

When I execute it from a program I wrote over a year ago, it works exactly as expected. But when I execute it from my new application from a different Venv, it throws up the above error.

This only happens with this specific execute statement. I know I am connected to the SQL server, because I query the database several times before this and get information, and I execute other stored procedures from the new venv and they work perfectly.

The ONLY thing in the code that is different is that in my 1st venv where this statement works, I setup the connection to the DB in just a regular function and make my cursor a global variable. In my new one with the problem, I set it up in a class, and I call the class later in my program.

WORKING Connection

```
def connect():
    try:
        global conn
        database = 'database'
        table = 'table'
        conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={};'
                              'Server=192.168.1.5\SQL-SERVER-01,9400;'
                              'Database={};'
                              'UID=username;'
                              'PWD=password;'.format('SQL Server', database)
                              )
        global cursor
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        return cursor
```

NON WORKING Connection

```
class connection():
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            database = 'database'
            table = 'table'
            self.conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={};'
                                  'Server=192.168.1.5\SQL-SERVER-01,9400;'
                                  'Database={};'
                                  'UID=username;'
                                  'PWD=password;'.format('SQL Server', database)
                                  )
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        except OperationalError as e:
            messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message='Error connecting to the Local server.')


........ later in the program 

        connect = connection()
        conn = connect.conn       # I use this conn and cursor to pass into my function that is
        cursor = connect.cursor   # actually executing the statement.
```

Lastly, when I run the SQL profiler and watch as I try and run this code from 2 separate environments. I am not sure if this is helpful or not, but I get this line for both of them

```
exec sp_sproc_columns N'insertpart',@ODBCVer=3
```

Then the one that works, the next 2 lines on the profiler are:

```
exec sp_unprepare 3
...
declare @p1 int
set @p1=4
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'...... ALL of the info I am trying to update into the DB.
```

The one that does not work, the profiler shows:

```
exec sp_unprepare 1
...
exec sp_unprepare 1
```

Comment: What python version and pyodbc version are you using?  I presume those differ between the virtual environments. Can you post the call stack for the error.  I'm somewhat skeptical that the python code you've posted is the source of the error.

Comment: That seems like an error bubbling up through pyodbc from SQL Server Native Client. I'd be suspecting different versions of the SQL Server Native Client between the two venvs. If it helps, data type `0x63` references the `ntext` data [type](https://www.freetds.org/tds.html#types).

Comment: @StevenEnsslen I thought it could be pyodbc before posting this.  I checked and on the one that works it was 4.0.30 and the one that didn't was 4.0.32, so i uninstalled 4.0.32 and pip installed 4.0.30, and its doing the same thing.  Both versions are using Python 3.8. I even pointed the one that isnt working to the python 3.8 inside the other venv and it changed nothing.  I am using PyCharm for both of these, open at the same time on the same computer, if that matters.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I will look into what exactly ntext is tomorrow. I am not sure exactly what that is.  It absolutely could be different versions of SQL Server Native Client. I have no clue how/where to check the version of that.

Comment: re: version check -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69215880/2144390

Comment: @GordThompson When I run that in both of my programs, both show the exact same thing: SQLSRV32.DLL and then 10.00.19041

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/b3MTwTwz) runs without error.

Comment: @GordThompson I am not sure how to replicate my issue. I was hoping more for some way to check other things that could be the issue or to somehow decode further the error message. Like I said, the code runs fine from one of my programs and does not run fine from the other. They are both in individual venv's. I am not sure what other settings PYODBC or SQL Server could be different between VENV's.  Thanks

Comment: @LazyPenguin can you upgrade to a newer ODBC version?  The one which you are using is out of support. https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some of the comments, specifically @StevenEnsslen I was able to run the command pyodbc.drivers() and see my drivers installed. Based on the github link he posted I noticed I was using an outdated driver in my pyodbc.connect() command. I changed my driver from 'SQL Server' to 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" and my program works perfectly now.

I cannot explain why. I am using the same computer to connect to the same SQL server with the same login credentials, and "SQL Server" driver works perfectly in one of my VENV's and fails in the other one only on certain commands.

Either way, I hope this answer is helpful in some other way for someone else. If someone else has more information on how/why this happens and wants to shed some light on the issue I will happily mark your answer as the correct answer. Thanks